# Why does my code produce TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this error has been asked several times, but I am stuck with my code for why it keep returning TypeError

```
def merge( s1, s2):
    if len(s1) == 0:
        return s2[:]
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return s1[:]
    minElm = []
    if s1[0] <= s2[0]:
        minElm.append( s1.pop(0) )
    else:
        minElm.append( s2.pop(0) )
    return minElm.extend( merge(s1[:], s2[:] ))

list1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
list2 = [2,4,6,8]

merged = merge( list1[:], list2[:] )
print(merged)
```

Basically, I want to merge *two already sorted lists (ASC)* into a *single sorted list* (ASC) using recursive method. I'm positive that my logic is correct, I just cannot get why am I getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Why am I getting the `TypeError`?

Comment: In general, when you have a problem you don't understand, it helps to print out intermediate values, or run it through the debugger or an [interactive visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html), so you can find the first value that isn't what you expected, instead of three steps later where it finally leads to an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`return minElm.extend( merge(s1[:], s2[:] ))` returns None, specifically because the `list.extend` method returns None. Instead, do one of the following:

```
minElm.extend( merge(s1[:], s2[:] ))
return minElm
```

or

```
return minElm + merge(s1[:], s2[:] )
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Jon has the correct answer as well but he's 30 seconds behind so I guess I will choose your answer. But I will upvote Jon's answer as well.

Comment: @Chilpol I was 22 seconds ahead actually ;)... but this is a much fuller answer that  points out how to correct it ;)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed someone else had answered as I was writing the code and went "screw it, I wrote this much, I'll post it anyway".

Truly the race to be the first answer is really annoying.

Comment: @DevinJeanpierre: Don't worry about the race to be first. Just write a good answer (like this one), however long it takes. If you find another answer that says everything yours did, you can always delete it. If your answer has useful information that nobody else has, then it's useful. What else matters?

Comment: @abarnert: You can always edit in quality later, no? Since I started noticing that trend, I've tried to avoid being put in that kind of situation, though, and this wasn't such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Here you're returning `None` (as `.extend` is in-place):

```
return minElm.extend( merge(s1[:], s2[:] ))
```